# Convert spaces of all sizes to a standard space in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Was just wondering if there was a clean way to replace all space character variants (half space, full-width space, Chinese space, etc.) with just a standard space?

Bonus points for replacing multiple spaces in a row (like 3 half-width or zero-width spaces or some of each) with just a single normal space.

Comment: when i hear the term "Bonus points" the first thing I think is homework assignment ...

Comment: If you use the unocode flag (UTF-8), then `\s+` is supposed to do that, but I have my doubts if php fully implements that.

Comment: Most Unicode whitespacey things are covered by [`\pZ`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: Use the `u` flag to make `\s` recognize Unicode whitespaces. I wrote an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29728633/3764814) detailing the meaning of this flag (basically, `u` is `PCRE_UTF8 | PCRE_UCP`).

Comment: @cmorrissey for your sanity, it's not a homework assignment. just looking for input on edge cases where random space chars might go undetected. thx

Answer (score 6):

I'll go with the obvious regular expression.

```
preg_replace('~\s+~u', ' ', 'your    input   here');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Thanks. Updated to english + added missing delimiters (been long day evidently).

Comment: `mb_internal_encoding` only effects Oniguruma, not the PCRE functions.

Comment: Remove that `mb_internal_encoding`, and add the `u` flag, then it'll work ;-)